# Get values from hash in URL using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

If I re-rite the URL using :

```
var id = 150
window.location.hash = "id="+id;
```

how to get the value of id using `jQuery` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No jQuery needed..

```
var id = /^#?id=(.+)/.exec(location.hash);
id = id ? id[1] : '';
// OR
var id = location.hash.substr(4);  // (when hash can only be #id=..)
                                   // This also selects 123 in #no=123 (!)
```

Comment: +1 - I don't know why people assume they need jQuery for everything.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w)'s answer not to use jQuery for this. But there're two things, i'd like to point out.

**1.)** Executing a regular expression, plus using a tertiary operator is *"overload"*, too. ;-)
**2.)** You should consider that some browers return the hash symbol, and some don't!

To avoid to truncate the actual value part, I'd say it's safer to use `replace()`, instead of `substr()`:

```
var id = location.hash.replace('id=', '').replace('#', '');
```

**UPDATE:**
I think `split()` is an even better solution:

```
var id = location.hash.split('id=')[1];
```

Just one (native) function call, which also *"checks"* if the request URL actually contains **a hash that contains the string** `"id=idString"`.

If it does, the value of `var id` is `"idString"`. If **not**, value of `var id` is `undefined`.